Add "Modified by" column when seeing Sharepoint folders in OneDrive
I use the "Add shortcut to OneDrive" feature and find it really useful to have Sharepoint files in my PC Windows Explorer. I see name, size, modified date... but not "Modified by" column as it shows in the Sharepoint web interface.
I tried adding more columns in Windows Explorer and the closest I found was "Owner", but that shows my Windows username for all files, not the Sharepoint user.
Is this feasible?
